# prefetch_size not working in Pika rabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, prefetch

I tried to use prefetch_size feature in Pika rabbitMQ.
My application is working when prefetch_size  is Zero .
Example:

> channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1,prefetch_size=0)

I am getting error while changing prefetch_size value.

> channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1,prefetch_size=10)

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, RabbitMQ does not support prefetch_size != 0
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-rabbitmq-extension/pull/114

However, the prefetch_count-parameter can be set to values => 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).